# How to get iphone X keyboard real size in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

This is a problem that occurs when experimenting with iPhone X.

I'm get keyboard size from this way.

```
let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
print(keyboardSize)
```

This is the first time the keyboard is up after running the app.

```
(keyboardSize = (0.0, 812.0, 375.0, 291.0)
```

However, once it disappears and then reappears, it always prints as follows.

```
(keyboardSize = (0.0, 812.0, 375.0, 233.0)
```

The numbers vary, but the actual keyboard size is the same.
Why does that code have different height values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` should be the answer

Comment: Oh! It Resolved.